# Validating data in MS Excel in Java

Tags: java, excel

How can I validate every data in Microsoft Excel before I import it in the database using Java? Should I use loops? But wouldn't it take much time in looping all data in the excel? example if i have more than 3000 data in Excel. What is the best way to validate bad user input in excel? For example bad date format or bad employee id format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave very little detail. I have done something similar to this many times. So I can at least provide some advice.

Assuming you know that each column should contain data of a given format you can validate each input cell with RegEx, i.e. the cell either matches a given RegEx or it doesn't.

1. If match then import
2. If not match then
   2a. If bad format then correct format
   2b. If invalid data do something
   2c. Reject entire row?
   2d. Prompt for user action?

All of the excel files I had to deal with were machine generated based on user input. So while I could have bad data the format was always correct. If you are dealing with human generated files then you are going to have to assume that at least some of the data will be bad format.

As to your question on speed, 3000 rows is a drop if the bucket. For my project I was forced to use Access/VBA which is dam slow. I was dealing with many files of 10,000+ plus rows with upwards of 50+ columns. The entire run time of the process was around 5 minutes to have the program access the website, pull the files, and load them into the database.

Java is orders of magnitude faster than Access/VBA. The only way you will know if your run time is reasonable is to run some test. Likely, I could have optimized the run time but as the code was only ran once a week there was no need.

Comment: Using the regEx will automatically correct the bad format that the user input in MSExcel?

Comment: Because all the data in the MS Excel were human input so the bad data format is inevitable. Is it possible to automatically correct the data in every column and rows in MSExcel before i can import it in the database it will automatically validated?

Comment: I find it easier to correct in code. Excel does have programmatic functionality but if you do not do it often you will find you spend more time looking for how to do something in Excel than in the language you are comfortable with. As to correcting bad data, it is a never ending challenge. RegEx will not auto correct bad data, it will only help tell you if the data is formatted correct or now. It simply looks for a pattern. If the pattern matches then your data is formatted correctly, else its not. Months after my project was complete I'd still find users found a new way to enter bad data.